# How to animate a conditionally rendered part of the component on state change using javascript and css?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component and some part of the component and that part is only rendered conditionally. When I click on a visible part of the component(button), it called the state change and renders the hidden parts. Now I want to fade in that hidden part instead of just show instantly. Is there any way to do that only with CSS and without using any external library like CSSTranstionGroup? Thank you for your help.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    showForm: false
  };

  render() {
    const { showForm } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ showForm: true })}>
          Fade in form on click
        </button>
    {showForm && (
      <div>
        <h2>
           This part needs to be fade in once the **showForm** is true
         </h2>
        <form></form>
      </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Include a custom class name for the outer dive.I am using the class name 'fadeIn'

```
{showForm && (
   <div className="fadeIn">
     <h2>
       This part needs to be fade in once the **showForm** is true
     </h2>
     <form></form>
   </div>
 )}
```

Add this to your *CSS* file.

```
.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeInAnimation 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```